# Unable download large file from Azure Storage

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azcopy, azure-storage-explorer

I'm not able to download large file from Azure Storage Blob container (using SAS ) to C:\Download. I tried Azure Storage Explorer 1.10.1 / 1.20.0 / 1.20.1 with Windows Server version 2012 R2 / 2019.

I also tried AzCopy. It is vhd file with size 127 GB.

It runs for about 35 minutes and then fails.

What is wrong with that? Can you please provide me with a working solution?

Comment: When the download fails, do you get an error? Please edit your question and provide error details. Also, your download could fail if the SAS token expires. Please check for that as well.

Comment: @GauravMantri how can I check if SAS token expires. BTW, when I upload 127 GB file to the same blob container it was successful.

Comment: You can check by looking at the SAS Expiry date (`se` parameter in your SAS token) or your download will fail with 403 status code if the SAS token has expired.

Comment: Do you mean this parameter ?  vhd?se=2021-09-24t08%3A26%3A43z&sig

Comment: Yep, that's it. Looking at this, I don't think your download is failing because of SAS expiration. Your SAS token is valid for one month. 2 things: 1) Please edit your question and include the azcopy command you're executing and 2) look into azcopy logs as it should have information about why the download is failing.

Comment: Log contains "the MD5 hash of the data, as we received it, did not match the expected value, as found in the Blob/File Service. This means that either there is a data integrity error OR another tool has failed to keep the stored hash up to date. When Checking MD5 hash."
I have to used the parameter "--check-md5 NoCheck" and download was successful.
Thank you for your help, @GauravMantri

Comment: Perfect! Please add this as an answer as it might help someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @gaurav mantri

- When the download from Azure Storage Blob container  fails try
  checking  the SAS Expiry date (**se** parameter in your SAS token) as
  your download could fail if the SAS token expires.
- If SAS token is not expired, look into azcopy logs which can have
  information about the failure.

Thank you [@gaurav mantri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/188096/gaurav-mantri) for the suggestion.

Solution found by [@majkl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1791180/majkl)  :
Log has the MD5 hash of the data  which did not match the expected value, as found in the Blob/File Service. This means that either there is a data integrity error OR another tool has failed to keep the stored hash up to date. When Checking MD5 hash.

Downloading large file from Azure Storage Blob container was **successful**  when  the parameter "--check-md5 NoCheck"  is used .